# Dynamic cell height issue with UITableViewCell autolayout jerk while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to do something like loading up different type of cells with custom height in a uitableview. The tableview cells are subclassed and consists of labels with the respective constraints. Each cell is having a dynamic height.

Now even before my table reloads the data, I am calculating the height that is required for the resizing of the cells and caching it in my model class so that I dont have to calculate the height when the data is rendered on the device.

To calculate height i did use the tutorial from **Ray Wenderlich** and I am having the right set of heights applies to the objects.

> Now the problem comes. Whenever I am dequeueing the cells there is a
>   kind of a small jerk that gives me an indication that my cell is
>   dequeued while scrolling.

How can i make these movement smooth so that there is no jerk while scrolling the view ?

The height is getting assigned in and does get the value as per the current type of data getting loaded.

> estimatedRowForIndexPath

Also I am calling layoutIfNeeded from my cellForAtindexPath

Suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: i am also facing same problem.. pls any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to say without seeing your code in cellForRowAtIndexPath, and without seeing your cells and their respective code. Here are some general questions I would investigate:

**What is the content of the cells and how complex is the view hierarchy in the cell?**

Even though you are supplying the correct estimated height, an autolayout pass still needs to happen, and a complex view hierarchy will take time to resolve

**Does the cell contain images?**

Images that need to be decompressed from a file (`UIImage imageNamed:`) can be intensive and cause scrolling issues, check images are not bigger than they need to be. If needed, bump this work onto a background thread.

**Are you calling a complex method to configure the cell for display in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?**

Look at the work actually being done in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, is there a complex method being triggered in you cell subclass or view model?

**Are you adding and removing views to the cell view hierarchy in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?**

If views are being added, removed, created, inflated from a xib, constrained etc during the cell config, this could slow things down. Try to do only what is strictly needed. Check if there is any code being run internally in the cell subclass during `cellForRowAtIndexPath` that could be moved to cells `initWith`... or `awakeFromNib` methods (ie code that could just run once when the cell is created, rather than every time the cell is displayed)

Also run the Instruments time profiler, see if that offers any more clues

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions @P-double. Will try to check my code against the suggestions made to see if there is some improvement to the performance

Comment: Sure thing, if you want to share some code with me on here or via github I can take a look too